# wikia template style attribute

Tags: css, mediawiki

I have made some templates on wikia.com, which contain only CSS code (key:value;).
My problem is having another template use these style templates in a style attribute tag.

```
style="{{MyTemplateStyle}}"
```

This code does not evaluate as expected. The CSS code is outputted before the element and the style attribute is not included inside the element.

Am I trying something not possible for a wiki ?
I merely want to be able to change styling on certain templates in **one** place, like regular HTML & CSS pages.

Comment: I ended up with using custom CSS classes which is allowed for admins (on your wiki, not entire wikia.com)

Comment: can I suggest you take a different approach. Explain what the problem is you want to solve (i.e. the end result) and I'll see if there is a different way to solve. Or (and?) give a specific example of the code you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styling specified from the `style=""` attribute **always** takes priority over any other css, even if you use `!important` in a CSS specification.

Therefore any edits you make to your CSS on Wikia will not ever override the CSS specified inside an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Kim, you were right to switch to classes instead of embedding in-line styles via templates.

The very idea of using templates suggest that this was going to be re-used in more than one place, applying styles to a group or, in fact, *a class* of elements.

This approach is much simpler to read and maintain (as you only have one, central place to edit), and also, if done right, will enable you to seamlessly change the colour scheme via Special:ThemeDesigner.